# Is the Scalaz disjunction \/ meant to replace the standard library's Either?

Tags: scala, scalaz, either

New to scalaz but am I imagining things here? Scalaz's / is meant to replace the standard library's Either but I am having problems getting the values of either sides. A simple test class comparing / to Either:

```
package com.example

import scalaz.\/
import scalaz.syntax.either._

class TestEither {
  def returnEitherScalaz(p: Int): \/[Int, String] = {
    if (p > 0)
      s"AOK".right
    else
      p.left
  }

  def returnEitherDefault(p: Int): Either[Int, String] = {
    if (p > 0)
      Right(s"AOK")
    else
      Left(p)
  }
}

object TestRunner {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val te = new TestEither

    val testValue = 1

    val resultS = te.returnEitherScalaz(testValue)
    println("result=" + resultS)
    println("isRight=" + resultS.isRight)
    println("isLeft=" + resultS.isLeft)

    val rightS = resultS.right.getOrElse("not right")
    println("right=" + rightS)

    val leftS = resultS.left.getOrElse("not left")
    println("left=" + leftS)

    val resultD = te.returnEitherDefault(testValue)
    println("result=" + resultD)
    println("isRight=" + resultD.isRight)
    println("isLeft=" + resultD.isLeft)

    val rightD = resultD.right.getOrElse("not right")
    println("right=" + rightD)

    val leftD = resultD.left.getOrElse("not left")
    println("left=" + leftD)
  }
}
```

produces the following output for right (testValue = 1)

```
result=\/-(AOK)
isRight=true
isLeft=false
right=\/-(AOK)
left=not left
result=Right(AOK)
isRight=true
isLeft=false
right=AOK
left=not left
```

the left (testValue = 0)

```
result=-\/(0)
isRight=false
isLeft=true
right=-\/(0)
left=not left
result=Left(0)
isRight=false
isLeft=true
right=not right
left=0
```

Is this a bug in Scalaz's / or am I just crazy? I've tried from most recent Scala/Scalaz versions 2.12.1/7.2.8 back to 2.11.8/7.2.6.

Comment: You are in fact crazy.
    
    val rightS = resultS.right.getOrElse("not right")

Why are you calling .right on on a disjunction?

Answer (score 1):

`resultS.right` does not return an `Option[String]`, but the right disjunction of the disjunction (like when you're calling `s"AOK".right`). Since ScalaZ disjunctions are right leaning, the `getOrElse` function is also available to offer you a way of getting the right side. You are thus calling `getOrElse` on an disjunction, not on an `Option`.

With ScalaZ you don't access the left and right directly, but usually fold the result, map over it, pattern match, recover, etc. This would achieve the same result

```
def printRightLeft(l: Option[Int], r: Option[String]) = {
  println(s"right=${r.getOrElse("not right")}")
  println(s"left=${l.getOrElse("not left")}")
}

resultS
  .bimap(Option.apply, Option.apply)
  .bimap(printRightLeft(_, None), printRightLeft(None, _))
```